# Why do we use malloc or calloc when we have a simpler code in c?

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0, i;
    printf("Enter the size of array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = i + 1;
        printf("%d,", a[i]);
    }
}
```

May I know the difference between `malloc()` and `calloc()` and this code, because I guess both are fulfilling the need?

Comment: You cannot return an array like that from a function

Comment: Also VLAs are typically allocated on the stack which is very limited in size, so you can run out of memory (and invoke *undefined behavior*) very easily in more complex scenarios

Comment: Malloc and calloc are typically used to construct complex, dynamic data structures from a variable amount of data on which your program, and its many functions, operate.

Comment: Variable-length arrays (VLA) have local scope and are allocated on the stack - either of those attributes might not be convenient. I wrote a summary about different memory section types here: [What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277536).

Comment: @ashchk This always happens when we discuss VLA on this site: there's always someone who comes crawling out from underneath the rock they've been living under since 1999 and start yelling "not allowed, compiler error!".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that as per the latest standard, VLAs are not mandatory part of the spec. Allocator functions (`malloc()` and family) are the standard way of allocating memory for which size is only known at run-time.

Quoting `C18`, chapter 6.7.6.2/P4

> *[...] (Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support; see
> 6.10.8.3.)*

That said, there are other usage limitations in case of VLAs due to their nature, their lifetime is limited in the scope in which they are defined. For example, you cannot return a VLA, defined in a function from a function call, but if you use allocator functions, you can return the pointer, as it's lifetime remains until programatically released (call `free()`).

Comment: That is a big part, but IMO a bigger part is what UnholySheep mentions: you can't return these from methods.

Comment: This is a poor argument though, since as per any version of the C standard, `malloc` too is optional, since a conforming freestanding system only need to provide a certain amount of headers, stdlib.h not being one of them. Besides, a hosted system compiler not providing VLA support is broken and useless, VLAs themselves aren't particularly useful but pointers to them is an important part of modern C programming.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Agree, but that really depends on the usage.

Comment: @Lundin I think sir for freestanding envs, we need to take it case by case basis. I was thinking of a common minimal hosted environment for this case.

Comment: Also, VLA only became optional in C11 as part of a Microsoft ***kissing strategy, where the committee desperately tried to please Microsoft, who in turn couldn't care less about C since they've gone all in on C++. This is the sole reason for the useless Annex K bounds-checking fiasco as well. I expect "optional VLA" will blow over once the C committee realizes how little Microsoft cares about them and how bad some of these C11 changes were in practice. 9 years later, I've yet to see an "optional VLA" hosted system compiler or bounds-checking interface compiler.

Comment: know your audience! The guy asking the question does not seem to know the difference between stack and heap. So by discussing higher level concepts you are not helpful. Give him a rundown on the basics or point him to them. @Vineeth ignore these comments and check this explnation about the difference about heap and stack: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/#:~:text=Memory%20in%20a%20C%2FC%2B%2B,happens%20in%20function%20call%20stack.

Comment: @Spliffster Apart from the poor quality, that's more mindless simplications about "stack vs heap", which this post seeks to clarify: [What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277536). As the first paragraph of the answer says: ""Stack vs heap" is a common over-simplification and not really a meaningful one, since those two areas have quite different, specialized uses. And no, those are not the only memory regions used by your program." Overall I wouldn't recommend links from geekforgeeks or tutorialspoint, those articles are written by students.

Comment: @Spliffster Nowhere in any version of the C standard does it specify local variables are on a "stack".

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
int a[n];
```

declares `a` as a *variable-length array*.  VLAs are useful, but limited:

- They cannot be declared with the `static` keyword or at file scope;
- They cannot be initialized in the declaration - e.g., you can't write something like `int a[n] = {0};`;
- They cannot be members of a `struct` or `union` type;
- They cannot be arbitrarily large;
- They are not universally supported - they were introduced in the 1999 revision of the language definition and made optional in the 2011 revision;
- They cannot be resized after they are defined - the "variable" in variable-length only means that their size isn't fixed from one definition to the next.

Like any `auto` variable, they cease to exist when you exit their enclosing scope.

Dynamically-allocated memory has a few advantages over VLAs:

- The memory stays allocated until you explicitly `free` it;
- You can allocate an arbitrarily large block of memory;
- You can resize the allocated block as necessary;
- Unlike VLAs, `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` are supported by any hosted implementation;

If all you need is some temporary working storage within a function, you don't know its size ahead of time, you don't need too much of it, and they are supported, then VLAs are a good option and less messy than using `malloc` or `calloc`.